# How can I use Scanner.useDlimiter to read a certain thing only

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

i am trying to only read what is coming in run(...) inside of the clips but i am struggling to find how or any example to help. i am trying this code but it only reads what comes before and can't read anything if i only start with run(.

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("run\\W");
//       System.out.println(s.next());     
         System.out.println(s.next());     
         // don't forget to close the scanner!!
         s.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: "Dont forget to close the scanner"? Nono. You do __not__ want to close the scanner. You don't close stuff you did not make (and you did not make `System.in`. Please edit the question with an example input (as in, what you type in the command line), and what you'd like `s.next()` to return when that is typed.

Comment: As i said in the question, i only wanna read what comes in the clips when i type run() so for example, as an input run(hello world) and as a return "hello world"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it helps:

```
.useDelimiter("run\\(|\\)");
```